# Prolog. In a query, how to put a condition on a variable that I do not want in the results?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

Imagine that I have the following knowledge base which gives for each person his first name and his age.

```
person(mary, 39).
person(john, 24).
person(sandy, 17).
```

Now, I want to retrieve all the persons that are older than 20 years. Furthermore, I just want to collect their first names and not their age. Here, I want to retrieve `mary` and `john`.

How to do this generally in Prolog and more specifically in SWI-Prolog?

If we use a variable which is not anonymous, like:

```
?- person(X, Y), Y > 20.
```

Prolog will give me the values for both `X` and `Y` and I do not want `Y`.

I cannot use the anonymous variable `_` because Prolog cannot link its two instantiations. The following gives an error:

```
?- person(X, _), _ > 20.
```

So, how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you define a predicate

```
ofintrest(X):- person(X,Y),Y>20.
```

an query

```
ofintrest(X).
```

If you don't want to define a predicate you could also use double negation

```
person(X,_) ,\+(\+ (person(X,Y), Y>20))
```

Comment: Thanks for these 2 solutions, The first one has the drawback that I must modify my knowlege base. The second one is really the answer I was searching.

Answer (score 6):

This answer directly follows up on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893466/4609915) by @danielp.

With the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) of [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) you can have either one:

- show answer substitutions of all variables (*default*)
- do not show answer substitutions for variables like `_A`

For detailed information, read the manual of the Prolog processor you are using!

For [SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=root): [Environment Control (Prolog flags)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags).
 [`current_prolog_flag/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2).
 [`set_prolog_flag/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=set_prolog_flag/2).

```
stefan@Lenovo ~ $ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.15)
...

?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, Flag).   % get default
Flag = true.

?- _A = 1.
_A = 1.

?- _A = 1, X = _A.
_A = X, X = 1.

?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).      % toggle flag
true.

?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, Flag).
Flag = false.

?- _A = 1.   % watch out!
true.

?- _A = 1, X = _A.
X = 1.

?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, true).       % restore flag
true.

?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, Flag).
Flag = true.

?- _A = 1.
_A = 1.

?- _A = 1, X = _A.
_A = X, X = 1.
```

Comment: @MathieuVidal. The Prolog toplevel (REPL) **is** quite versatile; it helps me do a lot of I/O implicitly—simply by writing queries and reading answers—as opposed to using the corresponding read_term / write_term API.

Comment: @MathieuVidal. Want info on how other Prolog processors (not SWI or SICStus) behave in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a predicate as already posted in [CAFEBABE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34892653/3604121).
Alternatively, you can also give a name that starts with `_` to variables whose values should not appear in the answer (as you already noted, occurrences of `_` are always distinct variables):

```
person(X,_Age), _Age > 20.
```

**Update**: This is specific to the Prolog implementation. It works for SICStus, but not for SWI by default (see [repeat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917391/3604121)).

Comment: This solution is perhaps good for some implementations of Prolog but it does not work with SWI-Prolog. There, variables starting with _ are just used to remove a warning given by the compiler and their values appear in the answer. Anyway, your answer could be effective for other implementations of Prolog.

Comment: @MathieuVidal: You are right, I'm using SICStus and there it works the way I described. I did not consider that other implementations handle it differently.

Comment: s(X): also works with SWI, but needs to be explicitly enabled. see my post how it can be done.